# Pushing record in store with belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to push a new conversation into the store. I am using :

```
this.store.push('conversation', received_message.conversation);
```

In this line, "received_message" is JSON data returned from the server by a pusher event. The problem I get is that a conversation has a customer defined by a belongsTo relationship to my customers model. When I want to push, it tells me that Ember-Data expects a string or a number for 'customer' but found an embedded relationship.

I already have DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin defined with customer always embedded. What do I do? Right now, customer is returned as a JSON object.

Comment: Can you share your conversation model and serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys here is what I did. I hate to answer my own question as it means I didn't search enough before posting but here we are.

What I did is I sideloaded all my models independantly in my returned JSON. I set my customer and subuser to an empty value in my jbuilder. Then, I pushed (all separately) the customer, the subuser and the conversation into the store using these three lines :

```
this.store.push('customer', received_message.conversation.customer);
this.store.push('subuser', received_message.conversation.subuser);
this.store.push('conversation', received_message.conversation);
```

I then manually made the relations between the models by retrieving them with .find and assigning the customer and subuser with .then. Worked like a charm.